# Bulk add nested object for the same document with NEST

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nested, nest

I have an index in Elastic Search with this mapping:

```
{
  "properties": {
    "allSubjects": {
      "type": "nested",
      "properties": {
        "nuis": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "ignore_above": 256.0,
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        },
        "dateOfInspection": {
          "type": "date"
        }
      }
    },
    "iD": {
      "type": "keyword"
    }
  }
}
```

The nested object will have over 300K rows. But when I try to add it comes up with this error:

```
Invalid NEST response built from a unsuccessful (413) low level call on PUT:
```

I have thought to do this. I want to the 300K objects into smaller batches with 10K and add that one by one for the same document. But when I try to do it, it only saves the last batch so it overrides them.
I have tried creating the document for the first batch and then updating the document using this:

```
public bool AddToElasticObjectsBulk(SobElastic sobElastic)
{
    var chunks = sobElastic.AllObjects.Chunk(10000);

    if (chunks.Count() > 1)
    {
        var indexResponse = _elasticClient.Index(new SobElastic()
        {
            ID = sobElastic.ID,
            AllObjects = chunks.ElementAt(0).ToList()
        }, d => d.Index("my-obj"));
    }

    var leftChunks = chunks.Skip(1);
    for (int i = 0; i < leftChunks.Count(); i++)
    {
        var sobElastic1 = new SobElastic()
        {
            ID = sobElastic.ID,
            AllObjects = leftChunks.ElementAt(i).ToList()
        };
        var bulkResponse = _elasticClient.IndexDocument(sobElastic);// this is wrong i know but here is where i need help 
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Use an online JSON checker to validate your json is good.

Comment: @jdweng the json is good